# Application to organize a weekly schedule

Tags: project-management, time-management

I am looking for a scheduling application. The problem is the
following: I have several activities that are to be cut into 1 hour
sessions. Each activity requires a different number of sessions (but
the same every week). The total number of sessions per week is given
(for example 40). I want the sessions for each activity to be spread
as evenly as possible over the week.

Are there standard programming
techniques or applications available to do that?

I am actually more interested in learning how they do it, but knowing
of the applications would already help me.

Linux preferred.